# How to get all orders with maximum update_count value only?

Tags: sql-server

I have laboratory orders system and these orders can be update more than one time for example

```
order_id     test_id    update_count
10              1            1
10              1            2 
10              1            3 
11              2            1
11              5            1
12              3            1 
12              3            2
```

I want to select all orders without duplicates and select orders with maximum update count

I tried a lot and i checked WITH clients as and self join but always select statement returned all rows with all update counts not only maximum update count for each order_id

This is my Select statement:

```
SELECT LAB_RESULTS.ORDER_ID as 'Order Number'
      ,LAB_RESULTS.PATIENT_NO as 'Patient No'
      ,Patients.Patient_Name as 'Patient Name'
      ,Patients.Age as 'Patient Age'
      ,LabTests.TestName as 'Test Name'
      ,LAB_RESULTS.RESULT_NUMBER as 'Result'
      ,LAB_RESULTS.RESULT_REPORT as 'Text Result'
      ,LAB_RESULTS.APPROVED_DATE as 'Approved_Date'
      ,LAB_RESULTS.REQ_FORM_NO as 'Request Form Number'
      ,LAB_RESULTS.CUSTID as 'Customer Id'
      ,Machines.Machine_name as 'Machine Name'
      ,LAB_RESULTS.SAMPLE_ID as 'Sample Id'
      ,LAB_RESULTS.packageid as 'package id'
      ,LAB_RESULTS.GROUPID as 'group id'
      ,LAB_RESULTS.EXAMINED_BY as 'Examined By'
      ,LAB_RESULTS.EXAMINED_DATE as 'Examined Date'
      ,LAB_RESULTS.APPROVED_BY as 'Approved By'
      ,LAB_RESULTS.update_count


FROM LAB_RESULTS 

  inner join patients on LAB_RESULTS.patient_no = Patients.Patient_No
  inner join labtests on  LabTests.TestId = LAB_RESULTS.TESTID
  inner join Machines on Machines.Machine_id = LAB_RESULTS.machine_id

where LAB_RESULTS.APPROVED_BY is not null 
and LAB_RESULTS.SAMPLE_STATUS = 6
and LAB_RESULTS.update_count in (select max(update_count) from LAB_RESULTS where LAB_RESULTS.SAMPLE_STATUS = 6 and LAB_RESULTS.deptid = 2 )
and LAB_RESULTS.deptid = 2
```

I expect to get the following result :

```
order_id     test_id    update_count
10              1            3 
11              2            1
11              5            1
12              3            2
```

then i added this condition but this return only the maximum update count only not group by each order_id only the maximum for all orders.

```
and LAB_RESULTS.update_count in (select max(update_count) from LAB_RESULTS where LAB_RESULTS.SAMPLE_STATUS = 6 and LAB_RESULTS.deptid = 2 )
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: I'd use [dense_rank](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: How does that query relate to the sample and expected results you've provided? Your SQL has 18 columns in the `SELECT`, yet your data only has 3.

Comment: @larnu this is example only for what i need sample data not complete output to make it easy for readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> then i added this condition but this return only the maximum update
>   count only not group by each order_id only the maximum for all orders.

The only reason your `update_count in()` didn't work is because you didn't correlate the subquery.

Instead of this:

```
and LAB_RESULTS.update_count in (
  select max(update_count) 
  from LAB_RESULTS 
  where LAB_RESULTS.SAMPLE_STATUS = 6 
  and LAB_RESULTS.deptid = 2 
)
```

You need this:

```
and LAB_RESULTS.update_count in (
  select max(update_count) 
  from LAB_RESULTS l2
  where l2.SAMPLE_STATUS = 6 
  and l2.deptid = 2 
  AND l2.order_id=LAB_RESULTS.order_id   --correlate to outer query
)
```

Although I recommend also aliasing the table in the main query and using both aliases in the subquery.

Comment: Thank you its working as expected I tried to alias in main query and use self join but in inner join and subquery cannot see the alias name.

Comment: Not sure what you're saying, but there's no need for a self-join.

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your select statement:

```
,DENSE_RANK() OVER   
    (PARTITION BY LAB_RESULTS.ORDER_ID ORDER BY LAB_RESULTS.update_count DESC) AS rank
```

Then you will wrap that result in a WITH clause and select and filter doing something like this:

```
WITH base_query as (
the current query you have with the extra column I suggested before) Select order_id, test_id, update_count where rank=1
```

Comment: I will try this and inform you about the output thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE t1 
(order_id INT, test_id INT, update_count INT)

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES
(10,1,1),
(10,1,2),
(10,1,3),
(11,2,1),
(11,5,1),
(12,3,1),
(12,3,2)

SELECT * FROM dbo.t1

SELECT order_id, test_id, MAX(update_count)
FROM dbo.t1
GROUP BY order_id, test_id
ORDER BY order_id, test_id

DROP TABLE dbo.t1
```